# Can Founders/Changelings thrive (survive) in extremely cold temperatures?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, changeling

I'm not sure how hardy the Founders are. I was wondering what would happen if the Female Changeling, Odo, or another Changeling/Founder visited the Breen Homeworld. The Changeling in question must not morph to an energy-producing form; he or she (it) must remain in a "humanoid" form.

Comment: there is an episode where Odo and Quark are trapped on a mountain. Don't they almost freeze to death?

Comment: “The Changeling in question must not morph to an energy-producing form; he or she (it) must remain in a "humanoid" form.” Are *you* gonna stop them?

Comment: No, Q is. Or a Douwd.

Comment: @NKCampbell Odo was a human during that episode.

Comment: According to Weyoun the Breen Homeworld has a temperate climate.

Answer (score 3):

In [DS9: Chimera](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Chimera_(episode)) the changeling [Laas](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Laas) appears in the form of a warp-capable spaceship. He seems to be more than capable of surviving in the vacuum of space where it's rather cold as well as morphing into a mobile liquid shape **while still outside the Runabout.**

There's no good reason to assume that a Founder wouldn't be able to maintain a humanoid appearance in extreme cold temperatures.

[image]

Comment: I don't remember Laas morphing into a liquid shape outside of the runabout, but my memory of that series is lacking.

Comment: @T-1000'sSon - He overhauls the ship, then turns up inside as a liquid through an external vent. I think it's reasonable to assume that he became a liquid prior to boarding.

Comment: This is what immediately occurred to me as well, but makes me curious what was going on with odo in the episode @NKCampbell mentions above where it seems like odo is freezing to death.

Comment: @1252748 - Odo is especially incompetent as a changeling.

Comment: I thought that was during Odo's "human" stage. Maybe not.

Comment: At one point Laas is actual *fire* on DS9. I don't think he has problems with maintaining temperature.